# I want to use a variable value as ID in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my jquery i'm using a variable

```
var x = "ID1";
```

I want to use the variable value as ID in my jquery.

```
$('#' + ID1).val();
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you have a question about this?

Comment: And what error are you getting?

Comment: it is `$('#' + x).val();`

Comment: `$('#'+x).val()` should get you `$('#ID1').val()`

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
$('#' + x).val(); //since x is the variable not ID1
```